# cmake not compiling with qt4

Tags: qt, cmake

I am trying to build AMAROK on ubuntu 12. I have although installed Qt5 already but i am getting the following error. Please help me.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message): Could NOT find Qt4: Found unsuitable version "4.8.2", but required is at least "4.8.3" (found /usr/bin/qmake) Call Stack (most recent call first): /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:313 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1393 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) CMakeLists.txt:83 (find_package)
```

Comment: Looks pretty obvious to me: `Could NOT find Qt4: Found unsuitable version "4.8.2", but required is at least "4.8.3"`

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have already installed qt5. But cmake is not considering Qt5. Its compiling with 4.8.2 only. I just want to know that how can I change the default Qt versio nbeing used by cmake.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install version 4.8.2 of libqtcore. You can get this from the Kubuntu Backports PPA.

Add the PPA

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`

Update the package list

`sudo apt-get update`

Install the new version of libqtcore

`sudo apt-get install libqtcore`

Comment: Doesn't works. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Could you please paste the error message once more? And what's the output of `apt-cache policy libqtcore`?